# How to identify which UITableView is selected out of two available

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4.5

I have an UITabView iPad app, using XCode 4.5, Storyboards and iOS 6.  I have a UIView scene, with two UITableViews (one in the upper left quadrant, the other at the bottom half of the UIVIew).  My problem is that I need to identify which UITableView is being referenced for **numberOfRowsInSection** and also **cellForRowAtIndexPath**.  I have given both UITableViews names:

[image: image showing id]

I don't think this is correct because when I but a breakpoint on the **numberOfRowsInSection** it arbitrarily selects the lower UITableView (previousAppointments), never selecting the upper UITableView (clientList).  Code is follows:

```
//------------------------------------------------
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    if (tableView == clientList)  {
        int y = listOfClients.count;
        return 1;  //  return list of clients          <---------  TODO
    }
    else if(tableView == previousAppointments) {
        return 2;  //  return number of appointments for this client    <------------ TODO
    }

    return 1;
}
```

I need to be able to identify which UITableView is selected so I can populate it with the correct data.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should set up IBOutlets to each table view, and use that outlet name in the if statement

Comment: @spokane-dude, really? What you showed is a name you put in the Restoration ID field. Did you also create an IBOutlet called clientList, and connect it to your table view?

Comment: I saw the possible conflict, so I changed the Restoration ID fields for both UITableViews to have a prefix of "rid"... no change in the behavior of the code tho' (never comes back to set ClientList.

Comment: @spokane-dude, you didn't answer my question. Did you create the outlet and connect it to the table view?

Comment: Sorry, yes, I did... I did a CTRL + drag/drop from the Connections Inspector to the UITableView for each of them...

Comment: @spokane-dude, it should work if everything is hooked up right. Try logging clientList and previousAppointments in the viewDidLoad method of your controller and see what that gives you.

Comment: results of NSLog:
clientList: <UITableView: 0x932d000; frame = (0 0; 0 0); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = TM+BM; tag = 1; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x8ad1b40>; layer = <CALayer: 0x8ad1500>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
2012-12-14 11:51:45.829 saori[2231:c07] 
previousAppts: <UITableView: 0x9344c00; frame = (0 0; 0 0); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = TM+BM; tag = 2; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x8af9520>; layer = <CALayer: 0x8af90d0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>

Comment: @spokane-dude, I really can't explain it then -- it should work. You should post the code you're now using (if you've changed it) including any logs you've added.

Comment: I can't explain it either... I don't have data for the UITableViews yet, so let me close this and if it still doesn't work after I add the code for the data, I'll open a new Q.  Thank you for your time; I appreciate it... :D